# Extending SimpleNeo4jRepository in SDN 6

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

In SDN+OGM I used the following method to extend the base repository with additional functionality, specifically I want a way to find or create entities of different types (labels):

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class MyBaseRepository<T> extends SimpleNeo4jRepository<T, String> {
  private final Class<T> domainClass;
  private final Session session;

  public SpacBaseRepository(Class<T> domainClass, Session session) {
    super(domainClass, session);
    this.domainClass = domainClass;
    this.session = session;
  }

  @Transactional
  public T findOrCreateByName(String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("uuid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    // we do not use queryForObject in case of broken data with non-unique names
    return this.session.query(
      domainClass,
      String.format("MERGE (x:%s {name:$name}) " +
        "ON CREATE SET x.creationDate = timestamp(), x.uuid = $uuid " +
        "RETURN x", domainClass.getSimpleName()),
      params
    ).iterator().next();
  }
}
```

This makes it so that I can simply add `findOrCreateByName` to any of my repository interfaces without the need to duplicate a query annotation.

I know that SDN 6 supports the automatic creation of a UUID very nicely through `@GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)` but I also want to add the creation date in a generic way. The method above allows to do that in OGM but in SDN the API changed and I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes it helps to write down things. I figured out that the API did not change that much. Basically the `Session` is replaced with `Neo4jOperations` and the `Class` is replaced with `Neo4jEntityInformation`.

But even more important is that SDN 6 has `@CreatedDate` which makes my entire custom code redundant.